# Cant get text to append to file in python

Tags: python, linux, http, flask

Ok so this snippet of code is a http response inside of a flask server. I dont think this information will be of any use but its there if you need to know it.

This Code is suppose to read in the name from the post request and write to a file.
Then it checks a file called saved.txt which is stored in the FILES dictionary. 
If we do not find our filename in the saved.txt file we append the filename to the saved file.

APIResponce function is just a json dump

At the moment it doesn't seem to be appending at all. The file is written just fine but append doesn't go thru.

Also btw this is being run on Linino, which is just a distribution of Linux.

```
  def post(self):
    try:
        ## Create the filepath so we can use this for mutliple schedules
        filename = request.form["name"] + ".txt"
        path = "/mnt/sda1/arduino/www/"
        filename_path = path + filename

        #Get the data from the request
        schedule = request.form["schedule"]
        replacement_value = schedule

        #write the schedule to the file 
        writefile(filename_path,replacement_value)

        #append the file base name to the saved file
        append = True
        schedule_names = readfile(FILES['saved']).split(" ")
        for item in schedule_names:
            if  item == filename:
                append = False                    

        if append:
            append_to = FILES['saved']
            filename_with_space =filename + " "
            append(append_to,filename_with_space)



        return APIResponse({
          'success': "Successfully modified the mode."
        })
    except:
        return APIResponse({
          'error': "Failed to modify the mode"
        })
```

Here are the requested functions

```
def writefile(filename, data):

#Opens a file.
sdwrite = open(filename, 'w')    
#Writes to the file.
sdwrite.write(data)        
#Close the file.
sdwrite.close()
return

def readfile(filename):
#Opens a file.
sdread = open(filename, 'r')    
#Reads the file's contents.
blah = sdread.readline()    
#Close the file.
sdread.close()
return blah

def append(filename,data):
## use mode a for appending
sdwrite = open(filename, 'a')
## append the data to the file
sdwrite.write(data)
sdwrite.close()
```

Comment: So please show the relevant bits of code, like the `append` and `writefile` functions? What exactly does `can't get text to append to file` mean. Is there an error of some kind or nothing appears in the file?

Comment: What i mean by i cant get it to append to the file is i send a request that meets the conditions to be appended to the saved.txt file. The file sent gets created perfectly fine but the basename is never appended at all. append is when you keep the file contents of a file and just add to it.

Comment: The saved.txt file has is in the format of filename<space>filename<space>.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the **bool** object *append* and the **function** name *append* are the same? When I tried it, Python complained with "TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable"

Comment: Yep that was totally it, i figured it was something very simple i was over looking been look at it for a while. Thank you so much!!

Comment: As a side not : *never* use a bare `except` close - that is, unless you really want to spend hours debugging simple problems because you discarded all the useful debugging informations...